# MVVMCROSS Xamarin.Android 6.1.2 Library Navigation

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

could you help me to understand is it possible make navigation in platform library layer in last MvvmCross version.

My solution has the next structure:

- **Core** Layer
- **Library** Layer (Android Library)
- **WL** (White Lable) Layer (a bunch of android apps)

All my necessary code for android apps placed in **Library** Layer, in **WL** layer I just change some resources and images.

Earlier I used MvvmCross 5.1.1 and custom presenter works fine for Me, but in new one MvvmCross 6.1.2 with default presenter doesn't, couldn't find View for ViewModel. 
If i Move Activity from **Library** Layer in to any app in **WL** Layer it works fine.

**[MvxActivityPresentation]** **doesn't work in Libraries project ???**

Comment: Also, new navigation doesn't work with types
this.NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(LoginViewModel), hint); just freeze app.

Comment: Where do you have your Setup.cs (in your library layer or in your WL)?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Setup.cs` you need to override your `GetViewAssemblies` and add the assembly where your `Activity` is:

```
public override IEnumerable<Assembly> GetViewAssemblies()
{
    var viewsAssemblies = new List<Assembly>(base.GetViewAssemblies());
    viewsAssemblies.Add(typeof(MyActivity).Assembly);
    return viewsAssemblies;
}
```

Doing this you ensure that that assembly will be taken into account to find the `View` corresponding to your `ViewModel`

More info in [Providing additional View and ViewModel Assemblies](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/advanced/customizing-using-App-and-Setup?scroll=484#providing-additional-view-and-viewmodel-assemblies)

HIH

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!
In my structure, where is the right place for Setup file, in Library Layer or WL Layer ?

Comment: I'd put it in WL layer, i.e. where your Android Application is

Comment: you can get more info about Setup here https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/advanced/customizing-using-App-and-Setup